# Want to run ansible tasks on remote host

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

In my scenario i  have inventory of three machines localhost, host2 and host3. I want to run some tasks/commands on host3 while my ansible playbook is still playing on host2 without switching from host2 to host3 - is that possible? I can use local_action module but that runs the tasks on localhost but i want command to execute on host3 while i am on host2.  Would be great if some one can give pointers. Below might explain what i am trying to achieve:

```
 - name: Playing host2
   hosts: host2
   become: yes
   tasks:
    - name: run following commands on host3
      local_action: command <command1 for host3>
      local_action: command <command2 for host3>
    - name: continue to run host2
      command: <command for host2>
```

Is there any substitute for local_action such that i can run the commands on host3 and not on 127.0.0.1?

Many Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [delegate_to](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) in this case. In case you are running your play on a single host (a single host is mentioned in "host:") you can simply use delegate_to to delegate the particular command to some other machine:

```
-  name: Playing host2
   hosts: host2
   become: yes
   tasks:
    - name: run following commands on localhost.
      shell: hostname
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

    - name: continue to run host2
      shell: hostname
```

Also when your target list has group of nodes (specified group in "hosts:"), in that case along with delegate_to, you should use [run_once](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once) as well:

```
-  name: Playing on group of hosts.
   hosts: someGroup
   become: yes
   tasks:
    - name: run following commands on localhost.
      shell: hostname
      delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
      run_once: true

    - name: continue to run on group hosts.
      shell: hostname
```

**Edit:** A passwordless authentication will be used while connecting to host3 from localhost. So make sure that you have configured key based authentication already.

*Note: you can always put multiple plays in a single playbook. So if you have a set of commands to run on host2 and then a bunch of commands to run on host3, I would suggest use to use multiple plays in single playbook.*

Comment: Thanks @Shasha99 for your reply.

Comment: In my case I am having Localhost used as ansible host where i am using it to run  my playbooks. Which in turns creating new hosts for me (host2 and host3). i want to run commands on host3 and then come back to host2. I tried using delegate_to: host3 but then i am getting Failed to connect to the host via ssh. I dont want to run any commands on localhost. The examples you have mentioned i guess works well if i want to delegate tasks to localhost but in my case i dont want to delegate to locahost. Any idea how i can get rid of ssh error i am getting in this case? Thanks Again

Comment: '-name: playing host2

Comment: @DeepakPrasad, Make sure that you have configured ssh for hosts(key based authentication). i.e. a you must be able to do ssh to host3 from localhost (or your ansible server) without password.

Comment: Edited my answer as well

Comment: Yes @Shasha99 my ansible connects fine to both host2 and host3 when i play them in different playbooks. I get the ssh error only when i am trying to use delegate_to: host3 within host2 playbook :( this is i am trying:                   `- name: Playing host2
  hosts: host2
  become: yes
   tasks:
    - name: run following commands on host3.
      shell: hostname
      delegate_to: host3
      remote_user: centos
    - name: continue to run host2
      shell: hostname`

Comment: Whats happeing if you don't mention the remote_user i.e. keeping the user same ?

Comment: Also are you mentioning username and password in the hostfile for both the machines ?

Comment: getting the same error with or without remote_user. Yes mu hostfile is configured correctly as i am able to ping or use ansible playbooks fine on both all three hosts.  It all works fine if i delegate between localhost to host2 or host3 or host4 etc.. but delegate_to, for me at least, not working when i am using localhost as ansible host and delegating between host2 and host3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126334/discussion-between-deepak-prasad-and-shasha99).

Comment: I am a little curious to know how are you doing ssh to host2 or host3 from localhost. Try doing ssh from localhost to host3 manually and check whether it is asking or password or not.